# Несколько коллекций на одном Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Нужно отобразить несколько коллекций на одном Canvas'е. Сейчас сделано так - объединил ObservableCollection's в CompositeCollection и в xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LiftLobbies}" ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binging X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binging Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Lift}">
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Doors}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        ...
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Так вот дело в том, что если добавить в CompositeCollection несколько ObservableCollection с одним и тем же типом, то я не могу задать для них разное отображение. Т.е. можно ли как-то задать для коллекций с одинаковым типом разное отображение?

P.S. Объединение в CompositeCollection не принципиально. Главное сделать для каждой коллекции отдельное отображение на одном Canvas'е.

Comment: А не усложняете ли вы? Может просто сделать несколько отдельных <ItemsControl>, каждую свою по числу отображаемых коллекций?

Comment: @Bulson мне нужно отображение всех коллекций на одном Сanvas'е

Comment: А и правда, _зачем_ нужно именно в _одном_ канвасе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого вы можете использовать селектор шаблонов `DataTemplateSelector`, который будет определять то, как отображать ваши элементы.

Использование:

```
<ItemsControl ... ItemTemplateSelector="ResourceExtension SelectorResourceKey">
```

где

- ResourceExtension  (StaticResource или DynamicResource)
- SelectorResourceKey (Ключ ресурса)

Но вам все равно придется использовать одну коллекцию.
Это не обязательно должна быть `CompositeCollection`, т.к. можно просто объединить все коллекции в одну с типом `object`.

*Уточнение:*

Если у вас все 4 коллекции содержат элементы одного типа, то в упаковке в `object` необходимости нет.

В селекторе вы можете определить тип удобным для вас образом. Если правило для отображения связано не с каким-либо свойством объекта, а лишь на основании принадлежности к базовой коллекции, то вы можете сделать класс - обертку:

```
class Wrapper
{

public Lift Value { get; set; }
public int Key { get; set; }

}
```

где Key - ключ, который задает как отобразить ваш элемент.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как мне это использовать. Ведь имея 2 коллекции с типом Lift, объединенных в одну с типом object  или CompositeCollection, я же все равно не смогу задать для элементов одной коллекции одно отображение, а для элементов второй - другое, разве нет?

Comment: @Hekumok в селекторе вы определите логику, которая и будет отвечать за то, как вам отобразить ваш объект типа `Lift`. Могу написать пример, если нужно, только напишите по какому критерию вы определяете как отобразить элементы. Последнее предложение уже не актуально, думал, у вас коллекции разных типов